# Celery deployment strategy

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a task that build a task Server and I decide to use Celery.
My idea is that :

1. Build a celery worker Server on Machine 1
2. A Web cluster consist of some web servers running Django.

There are some task that `Django` website have to tell celery Server on Machine 1 to work.
For example :

When a new user registered , `Django` code will call the celery worker to send email somehow.
I read documents about celery, but I can not find any documents that show me how to call a "send email" task to the Machine 1 and  ask Machine 1 to send the email.

any idea ?
Thank you very much

Comment: Is it a requirement for the Machine1 to send the email, or is it ok if the celery worker sends the email by itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use django and celery together take a look at django-celery,

http://docs.celeryproject.org:8000/en/latest/django/